# Kiss psycho circus nightmare child possible 100% stage 2?

Tags: kiss-psycho-circus-nightmare-child

I am trying to complete the game with all the secrets, items and enemies killed for each level, but I can't find all items and enemies of level 2 I tried:

- Play in different difficulties to change the number of enemies
- Use the NextMonster cheat to search for missing enemies
- Use the NoClip cheat to explore the whole level

But I do not have positive results, I thought that maybe it's a bug of the game, although I would like to know if there is any tool to explore the maps of the game or if someone has passed this level to 100% without problems.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the name of the game? i can make a tag for the game for you

Comment: @Dragonrage It seems to be the start of the post, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiss:_Psycho_Circus:_The_Nightmare_Child), not sure how to abbreviate it though

Comment: @Angzuril i made a temporary one for now. ill make a meta to figure out a good abbreviation for it that one of the mods can change it to if need be

Comment: Huh, didn't think anyone else had ever played this apart from me. [Good times](http://i.imgur.com/ohPxxhd.jpg).